# Delphi 10.4.1 how to use Android JMediaSession_Callback in JMediaSession.setCallback

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm writing a mediaplayer for Android in Delphi 10.4.1. The app has a service that uses JMediaSession to show what is playing (JMediaSession.setMetadata) and what state the player is in (JMediaSession.setPlaybackState) and this works fine.

The JMediaSession.Callback is a whole other story! But, thanks to Dave Nottage I got it working now.

Contents of ExMediaSessionCallback.java:

```
package se.infinitus.ExsurdoPlayer;

import android.media.session.MediaSession;

public class ExMediaSessionCallback extends MediaSession.Callback
{
    private static final String TAG = "ExMediaSessionCallback";
    private ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate mDelegate;

    public ExMediaSessionCallback(MediaSession mediaSession, ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate delegate)
    {
       mDelegate = delegate;
       mediaSession.setCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
      mDelegate.onPlay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      mDelegate.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
      mDelegate.onSkipToNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
      mDelegate.onSkipToPrevious();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
      mDelegate.onStop();
    }

}
```

Contents of ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.java:

```
package se.infinitus.ExsurdoPlayer;

public interface ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate {

            public void onPlay();
            public void onPause();
            public void onSkipToNext();
            public void onSkipToPrevious();
            public void onStop();
}
```

Compiled with javac.exe from jdk1.8.0_66. The two .class put in a .Jar and the Jar added to my project.

Then I ran Java2OP.exe to create the ExMediaSessionCallback.pas

Contents of ExMediaSessionCallback.pas:

```
unit ExMediaSessionCallback;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Media;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  JExMediaSessionCallback = interface;//se.infinitus.ExsurdoPlayer.ExMediaSessionCallback
  JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate = interface;//se.infinitus.ExsurdoPlayer.ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate

// ===== Interface declarations =====

  JExMediaSessionCallbackClass = interface(JMediaSession_CallbackClass)
    ['{E1A7600E-A146-4AB9-9973-C1602FBF4F50}']
    {class} function init(mediaSession: JMediaSession; exMediaSessionCallbackDelegate: JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate): JExMediaSessionCallback; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('se/infinitus/ExsurdoPlayer/ExMediaSessionCallback')]
  JExMediaSessionCallback = interface(JMediaSession_Callback)
    ['{4D614E2A-CE76-4C7A-827E-E72690A001EC}']
    procedure onPause; cdecl;
    procedure onPlay; cdecl;
    procedure onSkipToNext; cdecl;
    procedure onSkipToPrevious; cdecl;
    procedure onStop; cdecl;
  end;
  TJExMediaSessionCallback = class(TJavaGenericImport<JExMediaSessionCallbackClass, JExMediaSessionCallback>) end;

  JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegateClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{961E91BA-961D-4918-9EAC-A5B53ECDE70F}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('se/infinitus/ExsurdoPlayer/ExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate')]
  JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{81A470A3-63F3-44B9-B4FC-1F0A0EC9513B}']
    procedure onPause; cdecl;
    procedure onPlay; cdecl;
    procedure onSkipToNext; cdecl;
    procedure onSkipToPrevious; cdecl;
    procedure onStop; cdecl;
  end;
  TJExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate = class(TJavaGenericImport<JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegateClass, JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate>) end;

implementation

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('JavaInterfaces.JExMediaSessionCallback', TypeInfo(JavaInterfaces.JExMediaSessionCallback));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('JavaInterfaces.JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate', TypeInfo(JavaInterfaces.JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

I then use it in my service like this:

```
 private     
   jms: JMediaSession;
   jexcallback: JExMediaSessionCallback;
   jexcallbackDelegate: TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate;

 in ServiceCreate
 jms:= TJMediaSession.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context, StringToJString('ExsurdoService'));
 jexcallbackDelegate:= TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.Create(self);
 jexcallback:= TJExMediaSessionCallback.JavaClass.init(jms, jexcallbackDelegate);
 jms.setActive(true);
```

Quite a few steps but it only took a day to figure it out thanks to Daves example!

2023-05-04
Added declaration of TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate:

```
type
  TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate = class(TJavaLocal, JExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate)
  private
    [Weak] FParent: TExsurdoServiceDM;
  public
    constructor Create(Parent: TExsurdoServiceDM);

    procedure onPause; cdecl;                                                  
    procedure onPlay; cdecl;                                                   
    procedure onSkipToNext; cdecl;                                             
    procedure onSkipToPrevious; cdecl;                                         
    procedure onStop; cdecl;                                                   
    procedure onSeekTo(l: Int64); cdecl;
    procedure onPlayFromMediaId(mediaId: JString; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
    procedure onPlayFromUri(uri: Jnet_Uri; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;

...

{ TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate }

constructor TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.Create(Parent: TExsurdoServiceDM);
begin
 inherited Create;
 FParent := Parent;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onPause;
begin
 FParent.Pause;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onPlay;
begin
 FParent.Play;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onSeekTo(l: Int64);
begin
 FParent.FMediaPlayer.seekTo(l);
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onSkipToNext;
begin
 FParent.Next;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onSkipToPrevious;
begin
 FParent.Previous;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onStop;
begin
 FParent.Stop;
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onPlayFromMediaId(mediaId: JString; extras: JBundle);
begin
 FParent.PlaySong(JStringToString(mediaID));
end;

procedure TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate.onPlayFromUri(uri: Jnet_Uri; extras: JBundle);
begin
 FParent.PlaySong(JURIToStr(uri));
end;
```

Comment: MediaSession.Callback is a Java *class*, so you need to create a *descendant* and implement the required methods. At present, this cannot be done in Delphi, so you would need to do it in Java. In the Java code you could declare an *interface* that can be passed to the class, much like this example: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Java/Base/Connectivity. The *interface* can then be implemented in Delphi, like is done here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/Features/Connectivity/DW.Connectivity.Android.pas

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @Dave! I've looked at your links and I'll give it a go. That said I'm not that confident I will make it work... Do you think it's possible to use the JMediaSession I already have in my service or do I need to create the whole JMediaSession in Java-code and use that in my service instead?

Comment: Although this is a quite old question this is the best description I could find about writing a mediasession callback to respond to headset keys. I do not get your example to work (my onplay, onpause functions are never called). That might be due to my definition of TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate which is not givn in your example or due to problems with the inclusion of the java code. How can I check whether android accepts my callback function? Could you include your definition of the TExMediaSessionCallbackDelegate and an example of your actual callback functions?

Comment: FYI I have upgraded my project to Delphi 11.3 and code above still works.